# MySql sort conditional based on column values

Tags: mysql, sorting, condition

I have a table with products where there's a column for price and stock.

I want the products to be display sorted by the following rules:

- All products with price = 0 go to the bottom;
- Then the products with price are sorted by:

  - if stock is greater or equal to 100 then they are sorted by price ASC;
  - else they are sorted by stock DESC and if there's a draw then sorted by price ASC.

So far I came up with `price = 0, stock >= 100 DESC, price ASC, stock DESC`
which seems to work correctly when there's products with stock over 100 but falls apart when there are none.

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
ORDER BY price = 0, stock >= 100 DESC, price ASC, stock DESC
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, what I have is something like this:

SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY price = 0, stock >= 100 DESC, price ASC, stock DESC

(I don't have access to the whole query because I'm using a framework but have access to the order part)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would work - although it's rather obfuscated:

```
ORDER BY 
    price = 0, 
    LEAST(stock, 100) DESC, 
    price ;
```

More clearly:

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN price > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, 
    CASE WHEN stock >= 100 THEN 100 ELSE stock END DESC, 
    price ;
```

Comment: Used the first one and worked perfectly. Thanks.